# jQuery plugin - jqTransform BUG value option on dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, jqtransform

If I have:

```
<select name="select2" >
   <option value="99">Big Option test</option>
   <option value="100">Option 2</option>
   <option value="101">Option 3</option>
   <option value="102">Option 4</option>
   <option value="103">Option 5</option>
   <option value="104">Option 6</option>
   <option value="105">Option 7</option>
   <option value="106">Option 8</option>
</select>
```

jqtransform does:

```
<ul style="width: 286px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
   <li style=""><a index="0" href="#" class="selected">Big Option test</a></li>
   <li><a index="1" href="#">Option 2</a></li>
   <li><a index="2" href="#">Option 3</a></li>
   <li><a index="3" href="#">Option 4</a></li>
   <li><a index="4" href="#">Option 5</a></li>
   <li><a index="5" href="#">Option 6</a></li>
   <li><a index="6" href="#">Option 7</a></li>
   <li><a index="7" href="#">Option 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Its loosing the real value!!**

I fix that by changing this:

```
$('option', this).each(function(i)
{
   var oLi = 
         $('<li><a href="#" index="'+ i +'">'+ $(this).html() +'</a></li>');
         $ul.append(oLi);
});
```

to:

```
$('option', this).each(function(i, k){
   var oLi = 
       $('<li><a href="#" index="'+ k.value +'">'+ $(this).html() +'</a></li>');
       $ul.append(oLi);
    });
```

Is this ok? am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do this, when you submit the form it will take the respective value of the option !

The index and value are not related to each other !